# Force cmake to use older boost library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, libraries

I want to compile a simple project using the Point Cloud Library. Unfortunately it uses an older version of the boost library as I currently have installed via official repositories.

So I installed the older libraries in `/opt/oldlibs/boost/libs`. I try to set in the CMakeLists.txt this new path, but somehow cmake still uses the current version installed in `/usr/lib`. Did I do something wrong in my `CMakeLists.txt` file?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 OLD)

project(cloud_viewer)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

# Add old boost library
link_directories("/usr/oldlibs/libs")
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
if (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
  set(BOOST_ROOT "/opt/oldlibs/boost")
  set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/boost")
  set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/libs")
endif (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED regex date_time system filesystem thread graph program_options serialization iostreams chrono atomic)
include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (cloud_viewer cloud_viewer.cpp)
target_link_libraries (cloud_viewer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

The (part of the) output of cmake is:

```
-- Boost version: 1.64.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   regex
--   date_time
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   graph
--   program_options
--   serialization
--   iostreams
--   chrono
--   atomic
```

But I need 1.63. What do I do wrong? I use arch linux, my current cmake version is 3.8.2.

### Edit

I updated `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 OLD)

project(cloud_viewer)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

# Add old boost library
set(BOOST_VERSION_REQUIRED "1.63.0")

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
if (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
  set(BOOST_ROOT "/opt/oldlibs/boost")
  set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/include")
  set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/lib")
endif (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)

include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VERSION_REQUIRED} EXACT REQUIRED regex date_time system filesystem thread graph program_options serialization iostreams chrono atomic)

add_executable (cloud_viewer cloud_viewer.cpp)
target_link_libraries (cloud_viewer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Cmake now understands I want to use an older version, but still can't find it. Did I do another mistake? I installed the older package by extracting the by packman cached version from `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/' and extracted it to`/opt/oldlibs/boost/`.

The usr directory looks like this:

```
usr
├── oldlib
│   ├── boost
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── include (contains all header files)
│   │   ├── lib (contains all libraries, static and shared)
│   │   └── share
```

This is a part of the cmake output:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1842 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.64.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Detected version of Boost is too new.  Requested version was 1.63.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
```

I also tried running `cmake` with the option `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/oldlibs/boost/lib` and varying the path. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Your edit implies your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is also wrong, try fiddling with the correct value for the path when you pass `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/oldlibs/boost/libs` (pick a prefix or try and drill down into the boost directory hierarchy, to find a path that `cmake` is happy with). Alternatively, your custom Boost does not ship anything to for `cmake` to find, so you may need to write your own `Find*` macro: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries

Answer (score 1):

Your `find_package()` seems wrong, as you don't specify a version requirement on it:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED regex date_time system filesystem thread graph program_options serialization iostreams chrono atomic)
```

This asks `cmake` for Boost with the understanding that "any Boost is fine". This assumption does not hold, you know it, and so you should specify the version you want:

```
set(BOOST_VERSION_REQUIRED "your version value here") # adjust as needed
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VERSION_REQUIRED} REQUIRED regex date_time system filesystem thread graph program_options serialization iostreams chrono atomic)
```

If that still doesn't work (because `cmake`'s versioning conventions lead it to prefer the newer Boost under the assumption that newer is better...), then you can specify `EXACT` to force the version.

```
set(BOOST_VERSION_REQUIRED "your version value here") # adjust as needed
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VERSION_REQUIRED} EXACT REQUIRED regex date_time system filesystem thread graph program_options serialization iostreams chrono atomic)
```

This is all [documented here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/find_package.html).

Comment: I added all your propositions to my cmake file, but it did not help. I tried to state my situation clearer in the question.